# Diffrents between the result of machine learning algorithm?

Tags: twitter, data-mining, libsvm, rapidminer, mlp

I am working on a text mining project that I use a labled tweets data set (yes or no earthquake related tweets includes 8000 samples) to train Naive, MLP (Deep Learning) LibSVM classifiers to classify (yes or no) Unlabeled Tweets (28000 samples) on RapidMiner. Here is the result of three Machine Learning algorithm:

**Naive**

Accuracy= 80%

Number of tweets labeled "yes"= 6056

**MLP**

Accuracy= 86%

Number of tweets labeled "yes"= 2300

**LibSVM**

Accuracy= 92%

Number of tweets labeled "yes"= 53

My question is why the number of labelled tweets are drastically different?

Comment: Look at the data, not just some summary score! Of those many tweets labeled "yes", how many are truly earthquake related (*read* some of them yourself!)?

Comment: I've check some tweets before, there are some real earthquake related tweets.

Comment: Some, or many? How many in the training data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the accuracy you're giving is coming out of the model building process on your labeled data set. This represents how well the trained models can "reproduce" the correct labels of your training data. The big difference of numbers of the assigned labels on your unknown, unlabeled tweets seems to indicate strong overfitting problems in your models. This means the models are very well trained to reproduce the training data, but fail to generalize on new, unknown data.

As a first suggestion, check your validation steps. There are basic techniques like Cross-Validation that try to avoid overfitting, but there are many possibilities to "trick" yourself by introducing knowledge about your test set into your training data.

However, without the specific process setup we can only speculate.

Comment: TNX, so how can I avoid overfitting? I already set the sampling type to Automatic in Rapid Miner.

Comment: That is a very basic (not easy!) problem you always have to keep in mind. I can only answer on a very superficial level: keep information of your test set out of the training set. Difficult for time-based data, since a X-Val does nothing there. Keep in mind that normalization models also transfer information about the whole data set and so on. Without your specific process and data it is difficult to help. Maybe read some articles about validation and overfitting to get a better undestanding. Maybe even consider taking some basic data science/machine learning training.

Comment: TNX, it was a comprehensive explanation. I changed kernel type (Poly to Linear kernel) and C (Cost) value and it worked for me.